# Summarize forest change by geometry, year

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, forest-ecology

I am trying to calculate the forest change from the Hansen Global Forest Change dataset on Google Earth Engine.

My end goal is a columnar output of forest change by year by county.

I was able to calculate the total net change from 2000 to 2018 using [this tutorial](https://ourcodingclub.github.io/tutorials/earth-engine/#R), but I cannot figure out how to break it out by year.

How do I summarize/reduce by a geometry AND a year? Do I have to loop through years?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should probably loop through the years. In the future, to get more detailed answers, boil down your problem to the minimum amount of code needed, and include it in your question. It's also very helpful if you include a link to the EE code editor, and share all your used assets.

```
var startYear = 2000 // Inclusive
var endYear = 2018 // Inclusive
var list = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear)
  .map(function (year) {
    year = ee.Number(year)
    return calculateForestChange(year)
  })

function calculateForestChange(year) {
  return year // TODO: Calculate your forest change
}

print(list)
```